# RewriteBase in .htacces when you have multiple directories under the root

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp

Inside my root I have too many sub-folders of different projects. Currently I'm wornking on a cakephp one and I had to set the .htaccess files so that I can access to the index.php.

here are the different .htaccess files that I have created:

in **htdocs** of lampp:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^$ carte_drin/app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) carte_drin/app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In **carte_drin** cakephp project folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /carte_drin/
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In **app** folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /carte_drin/app/
    RewriteRule    ^$   webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

In **webroot** folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /carte_drin/app/webroot/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

My issue is when I try to access to another project I'm directed to the **carte_drin** project. I believe that the rewrite rule of .htaccess file in htdocs causes the problem.

I need a way to make the .htaccess points at each project folder of the root.

Comment: You should rather set up proper virtual hosts for your individual projects …

Comment: Can you  explain a little bit more?

Comment: Right now you are accessing this in your browser via `http://localhost/project1/`, `http://localhost/project-xy/`, etc., right? Instead, you should set this up so that each project is available under its own domain name, having the document root for that domain point directly to the respective project folder. Then you should be able to work with the “default” rewriting those frameworks come with, without having to make manual adjustments. http://dasunhegoda.com/what-how-to-apache-virtual-host/444/

Answer (score 1):

Set up proper Virtual Hosts. In your apache conf folder, first open the main conf and uncomment the line including the `httpd-vhosts.conf`. In the extra subdirectory, you'll find `httpd-vhosts.conf`. Open that up, and add a host config for each site. You should be able to remove `.htaccess` files, putting any of that info into the vhost config. Here I set up `dev.example.com`, which sits in `/var/www/devsite`, with the index.php sitting in `/var/www/devsite/public/index.php`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/devsite/public"
    ServerName dev.example.com
    ServerAdmin delboy1978uk@gmail.com
    ErrorLog "/var/www/devsite/logs/error_log"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
    <Directory "/var/www/devsite">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        FallbackResource /index.php
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

Once you've done that, edit `/etc/hosts` on your Linux or Mac Laptop, or `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows, adding the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.example.com
```

Then restart your apache, fire up your browser, and head to dev.example.com. Your site is now up and running on Virtual Hosts!

Comment: I'm a newbie and I'm just getting to learn this stuff. When I opened the httpd-vhosts.conf I found two <VirtualHost *:80>...</VirtualHost> blocs Do I have to change them both?

Comment: those are just samples, you can comment them out or remove them. Try the one I gave you!

Comment: I'm using a distant server and /etc/hosts where can be found?

Comment: that's the full path on linux!

Comment: I found this two lines in hosts file  : 127.0.0.1 localhost vps210798.ovh.net 
#51.254.205.243 vps210798.ovh.net vps210798. I'm using 51.254.205.243 in my url to access to my projects. Do I have to use it instead of the other ip address and also the changed lines of httpd-vhosts.conf  file are in the /etc of  the apache2 of xampp. Yet there is no hosts in /opt/lampp/etc

Comment: Tried your solution but when I run dev.example.com they tell me We can’t connect to the server at dev.example.com.
If that address is correct, here are three other things you can try:

Comment: here is my  httpd-vhosts.conf  content : <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
    ServerName dev.example.com
    ServerAdmin zakaria.mouqcit@gmail.com
    ErrorLog "/opt/lampp/logs/error_log"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        FallbackResource /index.php
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>

Comment: You'll need to change that. You have 3 sites or so, so you'll need 3 virtual host entries. Fix the folders for each project

Comment: I did not get you

Comment: you made ONE virtual host. and you made it the parent folder of all your projects! dont do that. make one for each project

Comment: Thank you I will try it

Comment: I added these lines in my htppd.vhosts : <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName carte_drin.local
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/carte_drin"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/carte_drin">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
then I configures this in /etc/hosts : 127.0.0.1       carte_drin.local
yet I cant' make it work do you what I'm missing